# How to center particular sections?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I am a very new in LaTex. Can anybody help me with this: I need that some my sections will be centred and without a number, but other  will be with the number and be aligned to the begining of text. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%Делает заголовки(\section) по центру и полужирным шрифтом
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\centering}{\thesection}{1ex}{}
\newcommand{\anonsection}[1]{\section*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
...
\anonsection{Введение}

   Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...

\section{Эксперимент}

Для проведения эксперимента...
```

So, you can see that I create a new command for sections without number. And I have this[image] [image]

But I need this[image]
I need only sections with number will be like in the 3rd picture. I searched answers on this site, but did not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define separately the formatting for numbered and unnumbered titles.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\hspace{\parindent}}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\centering}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\newcommand{\anonsection}[1]{%
  \section*{\centering#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\anonsection{Введение}

Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...
Эффект Тальбота --- это явление дифракционного...

\section{Эксперимент}

Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...

Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...
Для проведения эксперимента...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the `indentafter` option. Also `spelling=modern` is not necessary as it is the default.